# Python Popen versus os.system

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, popen, os.system

I'm on Mac OS UNIX and I can execute the following command in the shell:

```
./executable filename -r -w=/tmp --additional-arguments "-benchmark this_file.xml"
```

and I can get it to work in python using an os.system command:

```
os.system ('./executable filename -r -w=/tmp --additional-arguments "-benchmark this_file.xml"')
```

problem is that it waits for the executable to finish, and I want it to run concurrently with my python script, so I assume I want to use Popen as such:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['./executable','filename','-r','-w=/tmp','--additional-arguments','"-benchmark this_file.xml"'])
```

all files are either in the current working directory or fully specified

but no matter how I use Popen, even if I run it into one large string with a shell=True at the end, the executable does not launch.

Any ideas?

Comment: try without the "./"

Comment: You don't want the double-quotes in that last parameter - they're needed in the shell to make it a single parameter despite the included space, but you're doing the parameter splitting yourself here.

Comment: BTW, going forward, be sure to include the *actual* error or exception in your questions -- you almost certainly got a different error in your `shell=True` test than in the ones shown here, but "doesn't work" or "does not launch" is too vague to allow details to be distinguished. Including the details of the specific error also helps to ensure accuracy in marking duplicates (for example).

Comment: ...for instance, in the third example, the command almost certainly *was* launched (in the strict sense of being invoked by an `execve()` syscall), but then would have exited immediately on account of bad usage (being passed unexpected literal quotes, whereas in the original/working use case the only quotes given are syntactic instructions to the shell and not passed to the actual command). Capturing any error message emitted on stderr would have done some good in terms of making a correct diagnosis more clear.